# How to use `reduce` to convert a base-10 number to a base-24 number?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have base-10 number 1000, I want to convert it to a base-24 number.

```
1000 = 1x24x24 + 17x24 + 16
```

So the base-24 number is `[1, 17, 16]` if I represent it as an array, and each item still uses a base-10 number.

I think it is not hard to use `for` to implement it:

```
let x = 1000;
let base24 = [];

for(let i=1;;i++) {
  let y = x % Math.pow(24,i);
  base24.unshift(y/Math.pow(24,i-1));
  x = x - y;
  if(x===0) {
    break;
  }
}

console.log(base24);

// output: [1, 17, 16]
```

But is it possible to do it without using a `for` or `while`? For example, use a `reduce` method(from ES6)?

Comment: `(1000).toString(24).split("").map(x => parseInt(x, 24))`

Comment: @PM77-1 this works reverse of what asked.

Comment: The ESNexty version `function *numIterator(value = 0, base = 10) {
 if(value) {
    const digit = value % base;    
    yield digit;
    yield* numIterator((value-digit)/base, base);    
  }
}` [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/394ku240/)

Comment: `reduce` is not ES6, it's ES5 (although you don't need it here).

Answer (score -1):

Rework from [Juhanna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502381/juhana)'s comment, in ES5:

```
var toBase24 = function(n) {
    return n.toString(24).split("").map(function(x) { return parseInt(x, 24); });
};
```

Usage:

```
var a = 1000;

var b = toBase24(a); // [1, 17, 16]
```

Comment: Please do not change behaviour of JS native objects – such as `Number.prototype`

Comment: Sorry; as long as JS remains a prototype-based inheritance language and the intrinsic objects expose the prototype property, people can, and will. In general, it should be ok for those who know what they're doing...

Comment: Sure thing, but that doesn’t make it relevant in this answer and is generally considered poor practice, especially for beginners, of which SO is full.